# OpenStreetMap: Get height (z position) of street

Tags: openstreetmap

I am new to OSM development and I would like to use one of the APIs to FETCH data about streets. I don't really know which api I should use (because there are tons of suggestions) but I think imposm.parser looks good. (I prefer Python or online xml-rpc apis). I can get ways but how can I get the height position of these ways (is this possible? I dont know where and how to use key:ele or key:height from the OSM documentation).

So is it possible to get the height of a way or the height of a specific point (by lat and lon)?

(Using multiple api's is ok)

Answer (score 1):

OSM doesn't contain height data for all objects. The tag [height](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:height) is mostly for buildings and a few other objects. The tag [ele](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:ele) is mainly used for mountain peaks.

Streets and most other objects don't have a height information in OSM. You have to use a third-party height source such as SRTM, ASTER or something similar.

Comment: Ok - I will take a look at them. Thank you ;)